# Access Input Mask

Tags: ms-access, input-mask

I am not too familiar with input masks for access but I assume they are like those for say C#. Anyway, In a access 97 database, there is a Date/Time Mask of this - 99/99/00;0;_

so I am Converting this DB to 2013 and when I bring over the data, certain Dates don't get populated because they don't fill the mask. So for instance:

In my 97 db, there is a field using that Date/Time mask and the value is 10/3/107.

Now this value will not work when using it in the 2013 access.

I looked up documentation and examples for " ; " and " _ " and found this [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/input-mask-syntax-and-examples-HP005187550.aspx)

From the article regarding the ". , : **;** - /  "

*"Decimal placeholder and thousand, date, and time separators. (The actual character used depends on the settings in the Regional Settings Properties dialog box in Windows Control Panel)."*

Ok, so it is a placeholder, but what is the underscore then and why does it not fulfill the mask in 2013?..

Comment: Reference: [InputMask Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb242245%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: I am not sure why you re referenced my link, but I figured out the underscore at the end of the mask was just the placeholder before any data is entered. So it would look like: __/__/__
Simple enough. Still doesn't explain why it doesn't convert over though.